# Idioms / Proverbs - forgetting bad things, value of an ordinary life

Tags: idiom-requests, aphorism-requests

I've got two questions but they're very similar - looking for English idioms / proverbs.

(1) A proverb that means about the same as 好了疮疤忘了痛 (Chinese, lit. to forget the pain after the wound is healed).
(2) A proverb about the value of living an ordinary / uneventful life.

I'm ... pretty sure there's semi-common equivalents in English? I really can't think of them, though, so I'd like to ask you guys for help. c: Thanks!

Comment: That does not seem to be a very literal translation of the Chinese. I get *When the scar is healed, the pain is forgotten* as a literal translation -- but I'm depending on Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of quotations from wise individuals on both subjects, but you're asking for proverbs. I can't come up with one for the second, but *Time heals all wounds* would be a rough equivalent for the first.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment regarding the original idiom, that does not seem to be a very literal translation of the Chinese. I get When the scar is healed, the pain is forgotten as a literal translation -- but I'm depending on Japanese.

With that in mind, I might go with this:

> John 16:21 When a woman is giving birth, she has sorrow because her hour has come, but when she has delivered the baby, she no longer remembers the anguish, for joy that a human being has been born into the world.